# restsharp - no cookie in response object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies, restsharp

I have an issue with one of my requests to localhost server.

To authenticate, I need two cookies, one from sendReqForToken() method and one from sendLoginReq(string login, string pass).

In response I get cookie from sendLoginReq, but not from sendReqForToken().

I don't have idea why one request has a cookie second doesn't.

It is interesting that I get correct token(response content is correct) from sendReqForToken() method, but without any cookie in response header.

This is sendReqForToken() method body:

```
public void sendReqForToken()
{
    string adres = Globals.TOKEN_URL;    
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(adres, Method.GET);

    var client = new RestClient();
    client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
       {
           if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
               var tokenValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token.RootObject>(response.Content);
               DataManager.Instance.authToken = tokenValue.authenticity_token;

               if (response.Cookies.Count > 0)
               {
                   var cookie = response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault();
                   DataManager.Instance.cookieJar.Add(new Uri(Globals.TOKEN_URL), new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));
               }
           }
           else
           {
           }
       }); 
}
```

response.Cookies.Count  always is equal to 0. response.cookies property always is equal to null.

This is sendLoginReq method body:

```
 public void sendLoginReq(string login, string pass)
{
    login = "admin";
    pass = "admin";

    string adres = Globals.LOGIN_URL;
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(adres, Method.POST);
    var client = new RestClient();

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    try
    {
        request.AddBody(new
        {
            authenticity_token = DataManager.Instance.authToken,
            commit = "Login",
            utf8 = true,
            user_session = new
            {
                email = login,
                password = pass
            }
        });
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var cookie = response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault();
                DataManager.Instance.cookieJar.Add(new Uri(Globals.LOGIN_URL), new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    });
}
```

In second method I get correct cookie.

Thanks a lot for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, your server sends you a cookie with HTTPonly=true parameter, you should change HTTOnly parameter to false and then you can grab  the cookie from token response.

see this link [answer to your question](http://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock/issues/39)

Comment: Thanks, i fixed this issue a couple days ago. I changed HTTPOnly parameter to false in my ruby server. Now everything works great!

Comment: So, I added a new `CookieContainer` to `RestClient` and then after executing the request, the `RestClient`'s `CookieContainer` will have the cookie. Then I used `GetCookieHeader()` to get the actual cookie

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @KarthikNishanth. To make it clear:

```
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer ();
var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("http://domain_or_subdomain.ext"));
```

`var client` is a `RestClient`

After the `client.Execute(request);` the `GetCookieHeader()` will return the desired cookie

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the cookie